# pytables ImportError: DLL load failed while importing utilsextension

Tags: python, anaconda, importerror, pytables

My code contains the line `from tables import NaturalNameWarning` which causes the following error:

```
from tables import NaturalNameWarning
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Input In [4] in <cell line: 1>
    from tables import NaturalNameWarning

  File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\tables\__init__.py:45 in <module>
    from .utilsextension import get_hdf5_version as _get_hdf5_version

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing utilsextension: The specified module could not be found.
```

If I run `conda list pytables` in the *Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda3)* it returns:

```
# packages in environment at C:\Users\JB\.conda\envs\gloria:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
pytables                  3.7.0            py39h9d4cd68_0    anaconda
```

Does anyone know how I can resolve the error?

Comment: The error isn't telling you the module isn't installed. It's telling you it is installed, but there is a problem with a binary extension (DLL). It might be missing, or the wrong bitness. Can you find a `.pyd` or `.dll` of that name in `site-packages`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It seems to have been a problem with a version of PyTables being incompatible with windows (?). Now it seems to work. Link for reference: https://github.com/scverse/scanpy/issues/2108#issuecomment-1013605391

I will close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this issue is related to the version PyTables. I was able to resolve the issue by installing PyTables v3.6.1.

Source: https://github.com/scverse/scanpy/issues/2108#issuecomment-1013605391